# Blackberry Animation Issue on App's Home Screen

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to create an Application which has a Home Screen (`MyScreen` below) animation in Blackberry which makes an image float from the bottom to middle of the screen.  Then after that, i want to push another Screen which brings a Login Screen or something (`NewScreen` below).

I am getting a blank Screen after the animation. On pressing **back** once, i am getting the Screen i pushed from the Animation Screen. Please guide me: where should i push to get the perfect result?

```java
import net.rim.device.api.animation.AnimatedScalar;
import net.rim.device.api.animation.Animation;
import net.rim.device.api.animation.Animator;
import net.rim.device.api.animation.AnimatorListener;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.system.EncodedImage;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.TransitionContext;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Ui;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiEngineInstance;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.PopupScreen;

/**
 * A class extending the MainScreen class, which provides default standard
 * behavior for BlackBerry GUI applications.
 */

public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements AnimatorListener {
    private RectangleToMove _rect;
    private Animator _animator;
    private Animation _xanimation;
    private Animation _yanimation;
    private boolean _bAnimating;
    public static final int BALL_WIDTH = 50;
    public Bitmap splashimg;

    static TransitionContext transitionContextIn;
    static TransitionContext transitionContextOut;
    static UiEngineInstance engine = Ui.getUiEngineInstance();

    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */

    public MyScreen() {
        EncodedImage img = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("logo.png");
        splashimg = img.getBitmap();
        _bAnimating = false;
        int midScreen = (Display.getWidth() / 2) - img.getWidth()/2;
        int endScreen = Display.getHeight();
        _rect = new RectangleToMove(midScreen, BALL_WIDTH);
        _animator = new Animator(30);
        _animator.setAnimatorListener(this);
        _yanimation = _animator.addAnimationFromTo(_rect.getY(),
                AnimatedScalar.ANIMATION_PROPERTY_SCALAR, endScreen
                        - BALL_WIDTH, Display.getHeight() / 2-30,
                Animation.EASINGCURVE_LINEAR, 3000L);
        _yanimation.setRepeatCount(1f);
        _yanimation.begin(0);


        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new NewScreen());

    }

    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (_bAnimating) {
            _rect.draw(g, splashimg);
        }       
    }

    public void animatorUpdate() {
        invalidate();
        doPaint();      
    }

    public void animatorProcessing(boolean processing) {
        _bAnimating = processing;
    }


}

class RectangleToMove {
    private int xPos;
    private AnimatedScalar yPos;

    public void draw(Graphics g, Bitmap splashimg) {
        g.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.clear();
        g.setColor(Color.SLATEGRAY);
        g.drawBitmap(xPos, yPos.getInt(), splashimg.getWidth(),
                splashimg.getHeight(), splashimg, 0, 0);
        /*
         * g.fillEllipse(xPos,yPos.getInt(),
         * xPos+MyScreen.BALL_WIDTH,yPos.getInt(),xPos,
         * yPos.getInt()+MyScreen.BALL_WIDTH,0,360);
         */
    }

    public int getX() {
        return xPos;
    }

    public AnimatedScalar getY() {
        return yPos;
    }

    RectangleToMove(int x, int y) {

        xPos = x;
        yPos = new AnimatedScalar(y);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you work on rewriting your second paragraph?  I'm having trouble understanding what you're describing.  If possible, name your classes with descriptive names.  For example, is `MyScreen` what you're calling the "Animation Screen", and is `NewScreen` your "Login Screen"?  Which one looks blank?

Comment: MyScreen - Animation Class & NewScreen - Login Screen. Here after Animation get over one White screen comes totally Blank, when i put back on that white screen NewScreen Comes.. And i tired to Pop that screen of Animation but it says cant Pop null Screen..

Comment: @Nate - i Hope my question is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your problem, but I edited your question to describe what I *think* is the problem.

When your animation ends, you're seeing a blank white screen that you don't want.  You have to press Back/ESC to make the white screen disappear, so that you can get back to your login screen (`NewScreen`).  I assume you don't want to see the initial animation screen after it first shows (probably because it's a *loading*, or *splash* screen).

In order to do this, you need to wait until the animation **completes** before pushing your second screen.  So, **remove** this call to `pushScreen`:

```java
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new NewScreen());
```

that you have in the `MyScreen` constructor.  At that point, the animation has not completed, so it's too soon to push the `NewScreen`.

Then, push the screen when the `AnimatorListener` is told that the animation has stopped.  If you don't want the animation screen to be visible, when backing through your screens, then pop it after pushing the second screen:

```java
   public void animatorProcessing(boolean processing) {
      _bAnimating = processing;
      if (!processing) {
         // the animation is complete
         UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new NewScreen());
         // use this line if the instance of `MyScreen` should not be
         //  visible after the user presses Back/ESC:
         UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);
      }
   }
```